# Alternative of execScript() method for calling parent window js function in IE11

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer-11

We had a scenario where we need to call parent windows js function from child window. Till now we are using below code in js to call a parent window js function, where the function which needs to be called will be passed as a parameter.

```
function xxx(functionName) 
{
    window.parent.execScript(functionName, "javascript");
}
```

But, in IE11 this code is not working below is the error I am seeing in console:

"Object doesn't support property or method 'execScript' "

It looks like execScript() method is no more supported starting IE11. So, I am looking for any other approach to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: You provide very little information, but in my experience window.parent.nameOfFunction() works every time - as long as any parameters passed are correctly referencing their origin in parent/child.

Comment: thanks for your reply Tony. So, in this case as shown in the above code snippet "window.parent.functionName" will work?

Comment: That would be my assumption - I've done that lots of times - but as I said, you don't supply enough context for me to guarantee 100% that it will.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue in IE11: Object doesnt support property or method '<function name>'. If I find a solution Ill post it here.